# MVC3 EF Search DB fields but strip HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using the entity framework with MVC3 and am trying to do a search on a description field but the problem is that description field has HTML in it eg "< div class="section" />". Can i do a funky search that searches only the stuff outside of the HTML tags?

```
return context.Categories
    .Where(i => 
        i.Name.Contains(searchText)
        && i.Description.Contains(searchText)
    )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) a go. It has methods for extracting the text out of an HTML Document.

You basically just need to do the following:

```
  var doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
  var node = doc.DocumentNode;
  var textContent = node.InnerText;
```

Or the much less awesome method:

```
public static string StripHTML(string htmlString)
{
   string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";
   return Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, string.Empty);
}
```

All together

```
return StripHTML(context.Categories.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(searchText)&& i.Description.Contains(searchText)))
```

Comment: But would this mean that all the rows from the search are still found and pulled from the database and then stripped of their HTML? I only want to extract the rows from the database if there is a match to text outside HTML tags while the SQL is running. For example, if someone searches for section, but i have 2000 rows that only have the word section inside <div class="section"> then I would expect there to be 0 rows returned from the database.

Comment: There is no way to do this in the query. Your only option is to pull likely matches, filter the html out, then linq match records that contain your search string.